# How to use angular js inside expression engine

Tags: javascript

How to use angular js inside expression engine. Is there any article or tutorial is available for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your use context?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just now learning angular and plan to us it inside EE.  I've tested it out on my local machine running ee3.05 and I didn't have any problems.

Here's the simple test page I used that worked:

```
<div ng-app=""> <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p> <p>You wrote: {{ name }}</p> </div>
```

Of course you'll need to use the angularJS script somewhere...here's their CDN link: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js